# Botkit hoek vulnerability

Tags: javascript, npm, botkit

I cannot figure out how to update a dependent package included in Botkit.  After running npm install on the package.json below.  Npm warns that the hoek package is vulnerable.  I've tried running `npm audit fix` with no resolution.  When I run `npm ls hoek` it shows botkit installed hoek@2.16.3.  I don't see why it would install an out of date version.

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "deleteme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "botkit": "^0.6.16"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the npm documentation:

> As of npm@2.6.1, the npm update will only inspect top-level packages.
>   Prior versions of npm would also recursively inspect all dependencies.
>   To get the old behavior, use npm --depth 9999 update.

See more details here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Comment: No luck.  Ran `npm --depth 9999 update`.  `npm ls hoek` still shows 2.16.3